How to enter a "proper" address on Malaysia Digital Arrival Card (MDAC)?
I entered in Malaysia from Singapore last July, taking a bus across the border with no problems. For this trip I decided to check if Malaysia was one of the countries bringing in something like an ETA or ESTA and it seems the MDAC is such a thing.
No matter which way I try to type the address in, I get the same unhelpful cryptic error message "Please enter Address (In Malaysia) properly."

I've tried the addresses of two accommodations and tried adding and removing some of the parts of the address from the beginning and the end. I've tried removing commas etc. Nothing makes a difference. I've tried selecting "HOTEL/MOTEL/REST HOUSE" and "OTHER" from the "Accommodation of Stay" dropdown. Again no difference.


For reference, the MDAC is a digital version of the old paper arrival card, not a visa: AFAIK it's not possible to be denied (unless you hit a system glitch!) and it can be filled out at the border too.

@lambshaanxy My first impression was it was more like an ETA than a visa but then I started to think it might be more like the arrival form as you say. Everywhere says you have to submit it 3 days in advance but I think that's just poor English and they mean you can't submit it earlier than 3 days before your trip.

This is a partial answer, because it worked but it makes no sense to me.
The name of one place I was trying is "Motodorm Langkawi" and its address as on Google Maps is "Langkawi Mall, 54, Persiaran Bunga Raya, Kuah, 07000 Kuah, Kedah, Malaysia".
The form had two fields for the address. I put the name in the first field and the address, in many versions, in the second.
I had tried with and without the "Langkawi Mall" at the start of the second field, and without various parts at the end that already had their own fields.
What finally worked was when I moved "Langkawi Mall" from the start of the second field to the end of the first field after the place's name!
Maybe someone can find logic in this but it beats me.

Maybe it's looking for a house number at the beginning of the address and rejects anything that doesn't start with a number?

@lambshaanxy I tried it starting with a number with and without a comma after it many times and that didn't satisfy the form.

As a Malaysian I would fill it this way:
Line 1: Motodorm Langkawi
Line 2: 54, Persiaran Bunga Raya
State: Kedah
City: Kuah
Postcode: 07000
Looking up Motodorm Langkawi on my side, the Langkawi Mall seems to almost be an optional part of the address. Motodorm's Tripadvisor page doesn't have it, Booking.com has it after Persiaran Bunga Raya. I personally haven't been to Langkawi so I can't say for sure what Langkawi Mall actually refers to, but a look at Google Street View suggests that it's not something that would throw off the address.
As a note, the required format could simply be a weirdness with the Immigration Department's form. Not unheard of for some of our government sites.

Thanks. That's exactly how I interpreted it and how I tried it quite a few times. But what finally worked was to move the "Langkawi Mall" part from the start of Line 2 and move it to the end of line 1 with a comma between! It's actually in Kuah where there's still tons of empty and closed businesses that I guess didn't recover yet since the pandemic, and it doesn't feel like any kind of Mall but it also is an area with several covered shopping arcades and maybe the area was marketed as some kind of mall before it died? The hostel is cool though!

To register through the MDAC system, I encountered the same problem: the message "Please enter address in Malaysia properly" repeatedly pops up, but they don't give you the rules.
Google Maps and the booking website provide the following address:
"Hotel Oceania, Lot 60-64, Lorong Ikan Juara 5, Sadong Jaya, 88000 Kota Kinabalu, Sabah, Malaysia"
No matter how you combine words and lines, it never works, except if you add at the end of line 1 "Hotel Oceania Sadong Jaya".
Amazing trick.

It could be something as dumb as just requiring a comma somewhere in line 1! As much as I love Malaysia this sort of thing is very common here. Since it worked for you too I'm going to accept my own answer. I hope it helps other people. But I hope even more that they fix the e-form (-:
